# Traffic manager with performance routing method

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I have a Traffic manager with a performance routing method in Azure, in it I have 10 endpoints in different locations and 2 of the endpoints (two specific regions) have a massive amount of traffic.

What is the best way to avoid one endpoint to get massive amount of traffic? ( I don't want to attack one server instance with a lot of requests.)

Answer (score 0):

Performance routing is useful when you have endpoints in different geographic locations and you want end users to use the "closest" endpoint for the lowest network latency.

You should use Weighted routing when you want to distribute traffic across a set of endpoints based on their weight. Set the weight the same to distribute evenly across all endpoints.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#weighted-traffic-routing-method

Or you could use Nested Traffic Manager profiles to combine the benefits of more than one traffic-routing method based on your requirement.
You can combine 'Performance' and 'Weighted' traffic routing in your Traffic manager to optimize routing.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-nested-profiles